# Node packages not being installed inside global directory on Windows 8

Tags: npm

I am having troubles with npm, the thing is, even when I put in the global flag, `-g`, npm still installs new packages inside my `user/AppData/Roaming/npm` folder. How can I change this?

Comment: Yes, the same is happening to me. Most of my npm packages installed with `-g` before are located in `C:\Program Files\nodejs`, and lately they end up in `users/AppData/Roaming/npm`.. When I make a list of global packages `npm list -g --depth=0` only the ones under `users/AppData/Roaming/npm` are listed.. Very confusing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I think this is the default location for global modules on Windows. You can change that by defining the `prefix`property in config

`npm config set prefix C:\blahblahblah`